# How to use if statement when using linq to sql join?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, if-statement, linq-to-sql, inner-join

I'm using linq to sql on my asp.net project and i locked in somewhere. I select data amoung relationship tables and I use following codes. But the question is if supplierID is different than 0 there is no problem for query. Query is working as successful. But if supplierId is 0 query returns nothing. I want to use if statement when i join tables but how ?

My Codes,

```
EnvanterDataContext dc = new EnvanterDataContext();
var invent = from equipment in dc.tEquipments
             where equipment.EquipmentID == id
             orderby equipment.EquipmentID descending
join supplier in dc.tSuppliers on equipment.SupplierID equals supplier.SupplierID
join model in dc.tModels on equipment.ModelID equals model.ModelID
join equipmentType in dc.tEquipmentTypes on equipment.TypeID equals equipmentType.EquipmentTypeID
join equipmentStatus in dc.tEquipmentStatus on equipment.StatusID equals equipmentStatus.EquipmentStatusID
select equipment;
```

I want to use

```
    EnvanterDataContext dc = new EnvanterDataContext();
        var invent = from equipment in dc.tEquipments
                     where equipment.EquipmentID == id
                     orderby equipment.EquipmentID descending
if(equipment.SupplierID != 0)        
join supplier in dc.tSuppliers on equipment.SupplierID equals supplier.SupplierID
        join model in dc.tModels on equipment.ModelID equals model.ModelID
        join equipmentType in dc.tEquipmentTypes on equipment.TypeID equals equipmentType.EquipmentTypeID
        join equipmentStatus in dc.tEquipmentStatus on equipment.StatusID equals equipmentStatus.EquipmentStatusID
        select equipment;
```

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Actually, I'm using and i'm retriving value of it and showing with dropdownlist

Comment: Another question: can't you use navigation properties in stead of joins?

Comment: what do you mean with navigation properties ? Sorry I'm newbie for linq to sql. Generally, I'm using SQL Store Procedures, but I want to improve myself with other properties of visual studio.. thx a lot..

Comment: You should have properties like Equipment.Supplier. By these properties you 'navigate' from one object to another. So you can do things like `equipment.Supplier.Name` in your LINQ query in stead of all these verbose joins.

Comment: Thank you so much Gert, I changed my query and I removed joins and retrieved same result.

Comment: Erm... is that good or not? If it is, maybe you can add it as an answer. If not, maybe you can edit your question with the modified code.